# Why is Java running my batch files differently to when I double click on them?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

When I double click on the batch file, it works. When I try to run the batch file through Java, it doesn't work.

By 'it doesn't work' I mean that the batch file does run, but it doesn't run correctly. It runs 'sgminer.exe' with the --config. I can see that the config part works because it displays the configs name inside the sgminer.

Without going into too much detail, the error is that it doesn't think that GPU 0 is an openCL platform (it isn't, but 1,2,3,4,5 are). This is specified in the config to ignore GPU 0. I am including this error log, but surely if I am able to run it from double clicking on it, it should have the same effect as running it from cmd? What am I missing?

Here are the contents of the batch file...

```
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
C:\Users\miner\Desktop\LiteCoin\sgminer-5-1-0-optimized\sgminer.exe --config C:\Users\miner\Desktop\LiteCoin\sgminer-5-1-0-optimized\sgminer-fixed.conf
```

Here is how I am running the batch file from inside java:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
     Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\LiteCoin\\sgminer-5-1-0-optimized\\runme.bat");
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println(ioException.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer :)

Edit: before anyone asks, I tried to run it from cmd with 'start runme.bat', and it works. Likewise with just 'runme.bat'. Both work.

Comment: Just tried it, and it didn't work sadly. Thank you though, appreciated. It is running, I don't need to wait for it to end or anything, I just want it to run correctly as if i'm double clicking on the batch file in Windows.

Comment: "as if" - key part of what I said.. Move along if you're going to be rude. Am I being unclear?? When I run the batch file by double clicking on it, it's running differently to when I'm running the batch file through Java.

Comment: What is the default directory of your command-prompt?  Have you tried running it from there using the fully-qualified path to the runme.bat?  Also, how are you running the java - is it a stand-alone .class file or something else, is it a graphical application or is it a console application, are you running it as yourself?

Comment: Try using [this signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29) instead for exec, setting the default directory and any env vars that may be required.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the response. I am running this code via Netbeans. The directory of command prompt is C:\Windows\System32\system32\cmd.exe. No, I have not tried that yet, I will do that now. Also, thanks ManoDestra, I will try it after I have tried this.

Comment: Matt, you genius! It failed in the exact same way when I tried to run it through the full path from cmd in System32. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try adding a `pushd` or a `cd /d` to your batch file to set the correct current directory.

Comment: `setx` applies to future runs for that user but not the current console. Use `set` instead.

Comment: Hi Harry, I assume you mean "cd /" ?  I tried adding it to the batch before the sgminer.exe call, but it didn't have any effect sadly. Hi Noodles, I don't think that even needs to be there for the point of this, i'm sorry, should have just left it out.

Comment: I did it! Thanks Matt Jordan. Led me up the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the cmd to the location and then run it, and it worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your help guys.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"cd C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\LiteCoin\\sgminer-5-1-0-optimized && start runme.bat\"");
```